# How can I project one observable array to another with ngrx?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have a component

```
export class Test implements OnInit {
  public items: Observable<Item[]>

  constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>)
  
  ngOnInit: void {
    this.items = this.store.pipe(select(selectItems));
  }
}
```

My item is

```
export interface Item {
  timestamp: Date
}
```

I want to transform the `timestamp` from utc to local. So I want to do something like:

```
export class Test implements OnInit {
      public items: Observable<Item[]>
    
      constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>)
      
      ngOnInit: void {
        this.items = this.store.pipe(select(selectItems).select(x => new Item { timestamp = new Date(x.timestamp + " UTC") }));
      }
    }
```

The above syntax is not real (it's based on C# LINQ). I'm trying something along the lines of

```
export class Test implements OnInit {
      public items: Observable<Item[]>
    
      constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>)
      
      ngOnInit: void {
        this.items = this.store.pipe(map(state => selectItems(state), // something here...));
      }
    }
```

I'm stuck at the `// something here` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of C# LINQ select() is [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

So assuming your selectItems function returns an array, you can "map" your selected items to Items:

```
constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>) {}

public ngOnInit: void {
    this.items = this.store.pipe(map(state => {
        const selectedItems = selectItems(state);
        return selectedItems.map(x => new Item(...));
    }));
}
```